# MatToUIImage kills my app because of memory pressure

Tags: ios, opencv, uiimage, reference-counting

I am using opencv and want to display the image while processing it.
My problem is, when I use `MatToUIImage`, memory usage is increasing so much that my app crashes.

But what else can I do here? `image`is a member of the view controller and not instantiated in the method.
Maybe it has something to do with `processImage` being a delegate method of opencv?

```
- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)img
{
   image = img;
   testImage = MatToUIImage(image);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenCV on iOS. What is the type of `testImage` ?

Comment: The type is UIImage. Could be a bug in the combination iOS and OpenCV.

Comment: I saw somewhere that the signature is `UIImage* MatToUIImage(const cv::Mat& m)`, so `testImage` is a pointer. Do you release this pointer appropriately, esp. in case it is allocated at each frame ?

Comment: Well, iOS has automatic reference counting and so I don't need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reply to the last two comments:

AFAIK reference counting and releasing memory of pointers are different things. If you don't release the pointer then its reference won't decrease and won't be cleared from memory. No matter what, you need to release pointers.

Comment: I don't understand what needs to be done here. I'm experiencing the same issue. With ARC I cannot do [image release].

Comment: read this http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automatic-memory-management and if you read the answer again, it is very clear. If you are creating pointers, which are created in heap you need to delete them explicitly. Or if you are creating images on the stack then they will be deleted after they don't have any references.

Comment: I figured it out I don't know how I missed it. I just needed to wrap a @autoreleasepool{} around my code. I use @autoreleasepool many times, I don't know why it didn't click to use it.

Comment: OMG. @autoreleasepool is a lifesaver! over_optimistic It might make sense to promote the comment to the answer.